# Content Security Policy - unsafe eval error. Allowing a specific node_module file : node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js

Tags: security, node-modules, content-security-policy, unsafe-eval

I want to enforce CSP as a security measure in my web application.
From the server end , I have set the policy to "allow" self for all of its resources.
However there is one particular front end node_module file , which is throwing error as attached below.

The CSP header set is :
script-src 'self' '**node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js**'; script-src-elem 'self'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self'

Please help , I have been trying to find a solution for more than a week now!
Solutions tried:

1. Try the front end to make it ignore this file since it is an empty file. But I am not able to get it to ignore.
2. Trying from server end to bypass this particular file by changing the rules

TIA.

Update:
**Error message**
UnCaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as Javascript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"

at ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js

Comment: Please provide the error message.

Comment: @HalvorSakshaug UnCaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as Javascript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/73472256/content-security-policy-unsafe-eval-error-allowing-a-specific-node-module-fil#comment129764524_73472256d source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file seems to be allowed to load as it is loaded from the same source and you have allowed script-src 'self'.

The problem seems to be that the code in the file does eval(), new Function(), setInterval() or setTimeout(), which requires 'unsafe-eval' to be allowed. This is strange given that the file should be empty. Your console errer may provide you with a direct link to the offending code.

You could add 'unsafe-eval' to script-src. This would make your CSP less strict, but it is of course a lot better to set "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';" than to not restrict scripts with a CSP at all.